# Want to Cloth-Sim Mesh created with Geometry Nodes cant Pin Vertex Group

Tags: geometry-nodes, cloth-simulation, vertex-groups

I use Geometry Nodes to create cushion stairs. I can't get any data from the nodes to pin the geometry, the whole mesh just falls.

[image: the instances cubes indicate the face im trying to pin]

I am able to get the data to affect the material shader and can view the selection in a viewer node:

[image: Colors seem to like nodes]

In the Node tree I am instancing 1 Mesh Line onto another and extruding the mesh:

[image: The node Tree]
[image: inside node group]

I've tried multiple different ways of getting the data out of the node tree including a *Store Named Attribute* node but with no luck.

Here is a copy of the Blend File: [Blend File](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/fi5w9s23l7lz905fxy0se/BlendHelp.blend?rlkey=3ds3hydrq0wtb3w98dgubqq0d&dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Attributes and vertex groups are different types of data, looks similar though. Vertex groups are said to be replaced by generic attributes for a very long time, but for now they are not compatible. Currently, there are no nondestructive ways to convert attribute to vertex group. (You can modify vertex group if it exists though, but it doesn't work in all cases) The destructive way is the following. Apply *Geometry nodes* modifier. In *Attributes* tab, click on down icon and select *convert attribute*. Select mode to *Vertex group*.

[image]

Now you can use newly created vertex group.

Comment: That is interesting, in this video  https://youtu.be/7gEiTIor7ag?t=239  someone does something similar to what I'm trying to do but with a proximity node and it seems to work, looking at the comments It looks like something changed in ver. 3.2 however I can't seem to get the results I'm looking for even in 3.2 darn looks like i might have to look for a different solution

Comment: Yep, you are right. It is kind of regression. I've tried 3.1 and it works. But you have to change type of output to float and join geometry with original mesh (that has the vertex group)

Comment: that sounds great! , Would you be able to show me the node setup ? I tried in 3.2 and couldnt get it to work